# Vue.js - bootstrap table update consume too much memory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, html-table, memory-leaks

I have Vue.js component using https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table. In my component is `<b-table-simple></b-table-simple>`. The content of the table is loaded by AJAX. The number of cols and rows is dynamic (can be a quite big table - 40+ cols and hundreds of rows). When I load content for the first time, the table rendering takes about 1 second (I don't know how much memory it consumes). But when I edit table filter and reload content data it takes tens of seconds. A fan in my notebook is flying away... I am not sure if it is related to my issue, but when the filtered content is a similar size (cols and rows) it is quite fast (few seconds).

In my opinion, there is problem with memory releasing. I have found here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html I should destroy component manually? How?

```
<template>
    <b-table-simple>
        <b-thead>
            <b-tr>
            <template v-for="(header, colIndex) in data.headers">
                <b-th :key="'col-' + colIndex">
                      {{header.value}}
                </b-th>
            </template>
        </b-tr>
        </b-thead>
        <b-tbody>
            <template v-for="(row, rowIndex) in data.rows">
            <b-tr :key="'row-' + rowIndex">
                <template v-for="(col, colIndex) in row">
                    <b-td :key="'col-obj' + colIndex">
                        {{col.text}}
                    </b-td>
                </template>
            </b-tr>
        </template>
        </b-tbody>
    </b-table-simple>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "myTable",
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                headers: [],
                rows: []
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            let vm = this;
            api.fetchData(this.getFilter(), function (response) {
                vm.data = response;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

### EDIT:

---

When I changed `<b-thead>`, `<b-tbody>`, `<b-th>`, `<b-td>` and `<b-tr>` to common HTML elements, it is fast now...?

Comment: Do you see any output in the console?

Comment: What do you mean? No errors are there. In a network tab I can see the request takes about 500ms.

Comment: Something like this `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.` usually comes together with what you are describing

Comment: No :/ Now, when I'm testing it, it takes a lot of time only if the data changes. So, it is related to the updating of cells. When I click on filter button and don't change it, it is pretty fast.

Comment: I think you should look your keys. Using the index inside the key makes it re-render when the array changes

Comment: Don't you have an ID or a unique value on the elements you are iterating?

Comment: Yes, it is unique. I'm sure the Vue would warn me if not. Now a have new finding. When I changed <b-thead>, <b-tbody>, <b-th>, <b-td> and <b-tr> to common HTML elements, it is fast...

Comment: Yes, it is unique, but because is the index, it changes when you update the data (sorting. filtering etc). If the value of `col.text` is unique in all the fields, you can try to use it as key by removing eventual whitespaces `:key="col.text..replace(/\s/g,'')"`